# Producing a cmp and cmov instruction in V8 for x64

Tags: assembly, x86-64, v8

I am trying to implement my own version of essentially `Math.clamp` within V8 using the internal assembler.

I managed to produce a version of it using the Torque scripting language, and wanted to try doing a similar implementation using the CodeStubAssembler builtins. I realise that they are considered old school, but this seemed the easiest way to generate the actual assembly that I wanted. The goal is to make the compiler generate code as similar [to this as possible](https://godbolt.org/z/mFX9JZ)

The question is: is there an assembler routine that already produces `cmp` and `cmov` instructions? If not, how would I go about generating this?

This is only for educational purposes, which is why I am only interested in the x64 pipeline and treat all inputs as integers.

Comment: confused, why dont you just compile and then tweak the assembly that comes out of the compiler?  rather than whatever it is you are trying to do.  what is it you are trying to do?  get assembly from C?  write new assembly from scratch?  struggling with how to get an assembler to assemble?

Comment: are you trying to get the compiler to conform to a certain assembly language syntax?  or get it to generate specific instructions?   in either case that may or may not be possible, getting the compiler to generate specific instructions is a practiced skill and sometimes the compiler just wont do it as it is written to generate and optimize certain ways.   square peg round hole type of thing.  just dont understand the question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, let me try to explain

First off, I am working within V8 itself. It has the capability for you to write your own built in functions. I am trying to do something [like this](https://v8.dev/docs/csa-builtins)

I have successfully added a CSA builtin for Math.Clamp. The question is how in the V8 framework can I make the internal assembler produce the instructions described above.

Comment: You could shorten the critical path latency of that `clang` output by checking the original input twice, instead of having the 2nd `cmp` dependent on the `cmov` result.  That may change the result if `max < min` for some range of inputs, I'm not sure.  Anyway, that might require an extra `mov` copy if you were originally ok to destroy the input, and might not be worth it if the clamp isn't part of a long dependency chain.  Note that Haswell and earlier have 2 cycle latency for `cmov`.  Ideally pick the operand order so the 2nd CMOV's first uop doesn't read the 1st's output reg. IDK which order

Answer (score 7, accepted):

V8 developer here. The CodeStubAssembler is not designed or intended to let you control precisely what assembly instructions are emitted -- it is platform-independent, that's a big part of its reason to exist.

You can look at `MathBuiltinsAssembler::MathMaxMin` in `src/builtins/builtins-math-gen.cc` and its two call sites further down in that same file to see how you would express a sequence of min/max operations (or other conditional selections) in CSA. It is then up to the Turbofan backend powering CSA to select appropriate machine instructions on each platform. If you think that the machine code could be improved, then the way to address that would be to improve Turbofan's instruction selector (and/or earlier optimization passes) to detect the relevant patterns.

If you actually want to write platform-specific assembly by hand, you can do that too: instead of the CodeStubAssembler, you'd use the platform-specific MacroAssembler, which (on x64) exposes both `cmp` and `cmov`. There are a few such builtins left that you can study as examples, look in `src/builtins/x64/builtins-x64.cc`. There used to be more of these, but we have migrated almost all of them to other implementation techniques, like C++, CSA, or Torque, because reading/writing/debugging/maintaining assembly code is time-consuming and error-prone.

Comment: Thank you for this. I managed to implement the code that Torque produced for a `Math.clamp` operation using CSA which makes me feel happy. I will keep studying the usage of the macro assembler to see how I can write some assembly by hand. On a side note, is there a good resource of documentation where all of these systems are explained?

Comment: For anyone else who is wondering how to implement a builtin entirely in assembly code, a good example of this is `FunctionPrototypeApply`. It is entirely implemented in assembly code and you can see where everything plugs together. Hope this is useful to folks playing around with V8

Comment: The documentation (which you've already found) is at https://v8.dev/docs/csa-builtins and https://v8.dev/docs/torque. Besides that, the source code is the source of truth ;-)